# Block Reference field not being filled with Value using the Conditional Fields

Tags: 7, views, display-suite, entities

Hi I'm trying to add a specific block, based on taxonomy term that the user will pick from a field.

In more specific words, I have created a field linked to a Vocubulary and it displays like this to the user:
- Vocabulary
  - Value 1
  - Value 2
  - Value 3

And there is another field that is a Block Reference make me insert any Views Block that I have created.

What I want to achieve is that if the user selects **Value 2** then the value for the Block Reference field will be filled with a specific view block, like: **View: Value 2 Block : Teasers**

I tried with different sintaxis but the Block Reference field is not being populated... any ideas why? 
Thanks.